# Why am getting deadlock upon trying to run a Java AppEngine application?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I made an application Guestbook to learn Google App Engine with Java. However, when I try to run it as a web application, Eclipse stalls on building the application because it is apparently waiting for the workspace to build.

[image]

I tried canceling the building of the workspace by clicking on the red box to the right to no avail. I have also tried canceling the entire run and re-running, which produced the same scenario.

Why can't I run the web application?

Comment: Don't know why it happens, but a year ago I saw the same issue while building Spring application in SpringSource Tool Suite. So most likely it's Eclipse's issue, not GAE's one.